# Process a POST request with PHP from a JS fetch

Tags: javascript, php

I have an input checkbox styled as a switch [image]

```
<input id="Kim1043" class="form-check-input" onclick="toggleStatus(this) type="checkbox" name="Kim1043">
<label id="user-status-toggle" for="Kim1043"> $value['status'] </label>
```

where `$value['status']` exists in two states: `Active` and `Inactive`, information coming from a database.

I am trying to fetch a **POST** request with JavaScript so that when I toggle the switch, the database would be updated with the current status of the switch. I have a PHP function that would update the database.

```
function toggleStatus(radio) {
    var toggle = document.getElementById('user-status-toggle');
    
    if (radio.checked) {
        fetch("/dashboard?php=salespeople-tb", { method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify({ status: "Active" }) })
        .then((resp)) => { toggle.textContent = "Active" })
        .catch((resp) => { toggle.textContent = "Error" })
    } else {
        fetch("/dashboard?php=salespeople-tb", { method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify({ status: "Inactive" }) })
        .then((resp)) => { toggle.textContent = "Inactive" })
        .catch((resp) => { toggle.textContent = "Error" })
    }
```

Then, this is the **PHP** code:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    $js_response = $_POST["Kim1043"];
    return $js_response;
}
```

I don't know why it's not working.

**TL;DR**
I'm trying to run a PHP function when the switch is toggled.

Comment: Your code for fetch is same in both if and else statements. Hence it always marking as active.
Also, you are sending `status` but accessing `Kim1043` in php code

Comment: _Please do not suggest AJAX"_ fyi `fetch()` is AJAX. As for your problem it is because you are trying to post JSON data to php. PHP by default does not parse JSON requests into the super globals like `_POST` or `_REQUEST`. You also do not use the right field names, ie you used `status` to post but `Kim1043` when trying to access the information on the server

Comment: It's too complex, try $.post constructs with jquery, easier to understand and use. And come on don't use POST like this. Better if (isset($_POST['somename']))